# Google+ share issue

Tags: google-plus, ios6.0

In my app I am sharing some post to Google+. In this process, it is redirected to web page and shared.

My question is if the native Google+ app is installed in the device, is it possible to redirect to that app instead if web page?

Please find the piece of code here that I am using.

```
if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {

    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sample valid url"]];
    [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"sample prefix text"];

    [shareBuilder open];
}
```

Thanks,
Shashank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just released a new version of the Google+ for iOS SDK ([2-Oct-2013 v1.4.0](http://goo.gl/QHmyhb)) that now allows for your app to use native sharing so that your users do not need to leave your app to share content to Google+.

The following modifications to your code will enable the new in-app sharing experience:

```
if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {

    id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sample valid url"]];
    [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"sample prefix text"];

    [shareBuilder open];
}
```

For more information on this feature, see [Sharing to Google+ from your iOS app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/).

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I think its an even nicer experience!